Creating a new database in PostgreSQL yields an error "unrecognized locale provider: builtin"
I'm running postgresql-server-16.3-3.fc41.x86_64 and want to create a database for the XWiki wiki software.
Following the instructions as detailed here, I am supposed to issue the following CREATE DATABASE instruction:
CREATE DATABASE xwiki
WITH 
OWNER = postgres
ENCODING = 'UNICODE'
LOCALE_PROVIDER = 'builtin'
LOCALE = 'C.UTF-8'
TABLESPACE = pg_default;

When issuing that statement, I get:
ERROR:  unrecognized locale provider: builtin

This is unexpected as the PostgreSQL documentation states that builtin is a valid keyword. From the page for CREATE DATABASE:

locale_provider: Specifies the provider to use for the default collation in
this database. Possible values are builtin, icu (if the server was built
with ICU support) or libc. By default, the provider is the same as that of
the template. See
Section 23.1.4
for details.

Whence this error message?
As alternative, I can use a LOCALE_PROVIDER equal to libc, same as the locale provider for template database template1. In that case, the collation must also be equal to the one of the template database template1. That one happens to be en_US.UTF-8 (note that according to the documentation for Character Set Support, UNICODE actually means UTF-8, so there is no contradiction):
CREATE DATABASE xwiki
WITH 
OWNER = postgres
ENCODING = 'UNICODE'
LOCALE_PROVIDER = 'libc'
LOCALE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
TABLESPACE = pg_default;

This works fine.
Or one can use ICU with an appropriate ICU locale (though I don't know whether XWiki can deal with that. But it should, after all it's just a locale):
CREATE DATABASE xwiki
WITH 
OWNER = postgres
TEMPLATE = 'template0'
ENCODING = 'UNICODE'
LOCALE_PROVIDER = 'icu'
ICU_LOCALE = 'en-US'
TABLESPACE = pg_default


Oh okay, the answer is simply that I'm using PostgreSQL 16.3 whereas the builtin provider is only available in PostgreSQL 17.
PostgreSQL 16 manual

locale_provider
Specifies the provider to use for the default collation in this database. Possible values are icu (if the server was built with ICU support) or libc. By default, the provider is the same as that of the template. See Section 24.1.4 for details.

PostgreSQL 17 manual

locale_provider
Specifies the provider to use for the default collation in this database. Possible values are builtin, icu (if the server was built with ICU support) or libc. By default, the provider is the same as that of the template. See Section 23.1.4 for details.

So I will just try this and see what xwiki says:
CREATE DATABASE xwiki 
WITH 
OWNER = 'postgres'
ENCODING = 'UNICODE'
TEMPLATE = 'template0'
LOCALE_PROVIDER = 'libc'
LOCALE = 'C.UTF-8';

The database template1 cannot be used if I want a locale C.UTF-8 as template1's locale is en_US.UTF-8 for some reason.
